# Как сделать так, чтобы интерфейс и все сообщения VS Code были на английском языке

Tags: visual-studio-code

Установил VS Code 1.70.3 (максимально возможная версия для моего ноутбука HP 620 (Windows 7 x64 Домашняя расширенная). Пакет для русского языка не устанавливал. Установил расширение C# 1.25.4 (Microsoft). Интерфейс VS Code как и положено на английском языке. Но сообщения и меню расширения C# на русском.

Например: открыто окно с кодом на C#. Подвожу курсор мыши например к WriteLine. Показывается окошко с описанием метода частично на английском, а частично на русском языке. Другой пример: Устанавливаю курсор в такое место в коде чтобы появилась лампочка. Нажимаю на лампочку. Меню на русском языке.

Поиск в интернете показал, что нужно удалить папку X:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp...\.omnisharp\x.x.x-net6.0\ru. **И это помогло**. Далее ставлю в коде точку останова и запускаю отладку. В окне Run and Debug часть надписей на английском, а часть на русском языке. Также на английском и русском языках сообщения в окне DEBUG CONSOLE. По аналогии с предыдущим примером удаляю папку X:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp...\.debugger\ru и на всякий случай ещё и X:\Users\USER\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp...\.razor\ru. **НЕ ПОМОГЛО**.

**P.S.**
.NET SDK 6.0.405

Comment: Еще мб дело в текущей локали системы

Comment: Дело конечно же в локале системы. Но откуда берутся эти сообщения и надписи на русском языке? Не могу найти. Кстати менять локаль системы нежелательно. Это может повлиять не только на текст, но и на региональные стандарты.

Comment: Запускаете вы, например, код в VSC, а тот вызывает какую-нибудь другую программу, типа компилятора или отладчика, а те могут и не знать про настройки в VSC, а работать от локали

Comment: Это понятно. Но я использую стандартное расширение для VS Code (ms-dotnettools.csharp). IntelliSense и отладчик входят в это расширение. Настройки VS Code Display - English. По идее расширение должно было понять то, что я пользуюсь интерфейсом на английском языке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно мне удалось решить проблему самому.

Я удалил файл ru.pak из папки X:\Program Файлы\Microsoft VS Code\locales.

Может быть кому нибудь пригодится :)

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+P "Configure Display Language"

Comment: English (Current) - Это единственный установленный язык. Я написал это в своём вопросе.